# proj4 convert world coordinates to custom local frame aka how to set proj.def()

Tags: javascript, proj4js

here is a world coordinate for the center of river north, chicago `41.892571, -87.630712`
and here is where i want my coordinate system to be based from `41.881984 -87.629437` (south of river north in the loop, madison and state st)
i need a `proj.def(<help_here>)` such that when i transform the river north coordinate to my new coordinate system, it is x meters north and x meters west from the origin (at madison and state)

`proj4.defs('chicagoFrame', "+proj=merc +lat_0=41.881984 +lon_0=-87.629437 +units=m +no_defs")` this is what i've tried so far but im getting [ -1323.1922680083949, 5117321.60498216 ] which is way off. meaning its 1.3km west and 5,000km west of the origin

the right answer should be ~1km north and ~.1km west

my goal is to have local coordinates so I can say "a user is x meters away from the nearest post office" and from the very little that i know i dont think you can just subtract the coordinates from one another and even if you do you need to convert the difference in degrees to meters

Answer (score 0):

so i reverse engineered a solution but I have no idea why it works, or what easting/northing is and why you need it. i set but the origin and target coordinates to the same location `41.881984 -87.629437` and ran

```
proj4.defs('chicagoFrame', "+proj=merc +lat_0=41.881984 +lon_0=-87.629437 +units=m +no_defs")
proj4('chicagoFrame', [-87.62699284257677, 41.88005153127081])
```

the expected output is `[0,0]` but i got `[0, 5114784.278651999]`
so i adjusted the y_0 value

```
proj4.defs('chicagoFrame', "+proj=merc +lat_0=41.881984 +lon_0=-87.629437 +y_0=-5114784.278651999 +units=m +no_defs")
```

which output `[0,0]`
and now i have a projection that works, but better understand of how proj4js works